# What is the typical chemical composition of the most common asteroid types?

Tags: solar-system, asteroids

I'm trying to make a semi-scientific accurate game where you can find/mine asteroids. I want the composition of asteroids, and how common they are to be correct. Or at least as close to correct as possible.

Therefore I'm trying to come up with percentages of how common certain types of asteroids are, and what elements are typically present in those asteroids. Of all my research so far I found which elements are found in which asteroids, but never any statistics.

And of course, I understand we don't know much about Asteroids in the first place. Perhaps the data we have is not comprehensive enough to come up with any statistics, in that case, what statistics should I go with?

Comment: There are three main types of asteroids, as far as composition goes. The C-type asteroids are carbon rich and represent 75% of known asteroids, the M-type are metal rich, and the S-type are silicate rich.

Comment: Have you tried to google "composition of asteroids"? Or go on the wikipedia page? I'm sure you will quickly find results. After you have those and don't understand something feel free to ask more questions here..

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape thanks for your reply! I have, and I mostly find nickel-iron for s-type, about 10x as much for m-types, and mostly carbon for c-type. However, I have yet to find what kinds of elements are also present. I also found http://www.asterank.com/ which displays all kinds of elements are present, but again no indicative of percentages.